# Styled Component giving "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression" error

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use a ternary operator in a styled component and its returning this error "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression" error" not sure what i'm doing wrong.

`opacity: ${({ isOpen }) => {isOpen ? '100%' : '0'}};`

Comment: Typo?  Your (arrow) function is missing a `return` statement.  Presumably you want it to *return* something, and the error is simply telling you that all the function does is evaluate an express and ignore the result.

Comment: Yep - what @David said - just remove the braces around the `{isOpen...}`